# How can I get minimum and maximum values from different column1 and column2 group by column3?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, max, min

I have a table where I keep products `[prod]` and where they are sold and bought `[market]` along with buying and selling prices `[buy / sell]`. I want to get the minimum buying price and maximum selling price for each product along with market names. How can I get it done in MS SQL?

My table looks like this ;

```
id | prod |market| buy | sell|
---+------+------+-----+-----+
 1 |    a |  x   |  25 | 26  |
 2 |    b |  x   |  15 | 16  |
 3 |    c |  x   |  17 | 19  |
 4 |    a |  y   |  24 | 25  |
 5 |    b |  y   |  14 | 17  |
 6 |    c |  y   |  19 | 24  |
 7 |    a |  z   |  23 | 24  |
 8 |    b |  z   |  17 | 18  |
 9 |    c |  z   |  18 | 22  |
```

And this is how the table I desired looks like;

```
|prod|MarketMin|MarketMax| Min Buy  |Max Sell |
+----+---------+---------+----------+---------+
|  a |    z    |    x    |   23     |   26    |
|  b |    y    |    z    |   14     |   24    |
|  c |    x    |    y    |   17     |   24    |
```

Comment: use [row_number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @DaleK I can get min and max values per prod but I can not get the fields related with minimum buying market and maximum selling market. After this point I don't know how to go ```SELECT prod, MAX(buy),MIN(sell) FROM MARKETVALUES GROUP BY prod``` . I want to add which  which market I can buy cheapest and which market I can sell with most profit.

Comment: Look up the use of Cross Apply and do it once for min and once for max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `RANK()` in sub-query to achieve this:

```
SELECT mn.prod, mn.MarketMin, sq.MarketMax, mn.MinBuy, sq.MaxSell
FROM
    (
    SELECT prod, market AS MarketMin, buy AS MinBuy, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY prod ORDER BY buy ASC) as buy_rnk
    from MARKETVALUES
    ) as mn
INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT prod, MarketMax, MaxSell 
    FROM
        (
        SELECT prod, market AS MarketMax, sell AS MaxSell, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY prod ORDER BY sell DESC) as sell_rnk
        from MARKETVALUES
        ) as mx
     WHERE sell_rnk =1
     ) as sq
ON mn.prod=sq.prod
WHERE buy_rnk=1
```

Look at the demo in *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ed9c4b3409519db82195446c8f4203ab)*

***Edit:*** [Demo_v2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d5155736997c6e4059c41b2dad85f1ca)

*Demo_v2* has alternate query (without using `RANK()` but using multiple `JOINS` and `sub-queries`). *This method will be slower than `RANK()`*.

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for but didn't know what I had to look for. RANK() will be very usefull

Comment: Yes! We can also use `MAX()` and `MIN()` to achieve this. But that would take few more `JOINS` additionally. `RANK()` would be viable option.

Comment: If you don't mind how can I achieve the same thing with joins? It would be useful another time

Comment: @MustafaOzbalci, I have edited the answer by adding link to ***Demo_v2*** that has both the methods. Both will produce same result set.

Comment: thanks a lot it is pretty useful having different approaches to the same problem